# How to change value of a dynamically created Label in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, label, dynamically-generated

In my project, a label is created for each row in the database and added to a panel control. I need a solution to achieve the following :
When timer ticks, I want all those labels text values to get synced with System.Time.Now. And all those labels are named consequently. How can I access their .Text value from Time.Tick ?

```
For i = 1 To ds.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Count
  Dim NextPanel As New Panel
  Dim NextLabel As Label
  NextPanel.Controls.Add(NextLabel)
  MyForm.Controls.Add(NextPanel)
  NextLabel.Name = "MyLabel" & i
  NextPanel.Name = "MyPanel" & i
Next
```

And here I have problem calling those controls :

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ' I want each label's text to be Time.Now()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The controls referenced by the `Controls` collection property can be accessed by their name, like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    For i As Integer = 1 to ds.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Count
        Dim panel As Panel = CType(MyForm.Controls("MyPanel" & i.ToString()), Panel)
        Dim label As Label = CType(panel.Controls("MyLabel" & i.ToString()), Label)
    Next
End Sub
```

However, you may find it easier to simply add them all to a list when you create them so that you can access them later.  For instance, if you created a couple of lists, like this, as private fields on your form:

```
Private myPanels As New List(Of Panel)()
Private myLabels As New List(Of Label)()
```

Then, when you create the controls, you could add them to the list, like this:

```
For i = 1 To ds.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Count
  Dim nextPanel As New Panel()
  Dim nextLabel As New Label()
  nextPanel.Controls.Add(nextLabel)
  MyForm.Controls.Add(nextPanel)
  nextLabel.Name = "MyLabel" & i.ToString()
  nextPanel.Name = "MyPanel" & i.ToString()

  'Add them to the lists
  myPanels.Add(nextPanel)
  myLabels.Add(nextLabel)
Next
```

Then, when you need to loop through them, it is much easier and you don't have to be concerned with the total number that were created:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    For Each label As Label In myLabels
        ' ...
    Next
End Sub
```

It's worth mentioning, however, that what you are doing may be simplified quite a bit, if you added the labels to a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) control instead into separate panels directly on the form.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private panelList As New List(Of Panel)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For i = 1 To ds.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Count
        Dim newPanel As New Panel
        newPanel.Name = "MyPanel" & i
        newPanel.Size = New Size(150, 22)
        newPanel.BackColor = Color.Yellow

        If (i = 1) Then
            newPanel.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        Else
            newPanel.Location = New Point(10 * i + ((i - 1) * newPanel.Width), 10)
        End If

        Dim newLabel As New Label
        newLabel.Name = "MyLabel" & i
        newLabel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        newPanel.Controls.Add(newLabel)

        Me.Controls.Add(newPanel)

        // save panel in generic list
        panelList.Add(newPanel)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    // read panel from generic list
    For Each panel In panelList
        For Each control In panel.Controls
            If TypeOf (control) Is Label Then
                control.Text = control.Name + ": " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yy hh:MM:ss")
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Great, much appreciated for detailed answer.